# Automatically generating api annotations used for APIDOC

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, api-doc

I am creating API documentation and have decided to use APIDOC (https://apidocjs.com/) for generating my documentation. I am wondering if there exists a tool that can generate the inline documentation annotations automatically from my python api file.

This is the result i would like generated for me:

```
"""
@api {get} /user/:id Request User information
@apiName GetUser
@apiGroup User

@apiParam {Number} id Users unique ID.

@apiSuccess {String} firstname Firstname of the User.
@apiSuccess {String} lastname  Lastname of the User.
"""
```